# Replace string from html response

Tags: php, html, string

Am posting to a payment gateway url using curl which then responds with the gateway page.
The gateway page doesn't render correct because the stylesheets and scripts in the page are relative to the root directory.

Am trying to use php's `str_replace` to change the url but it doesnt seem to work

```
//make request to interswitch
        $url = "https://webpay.interswitchng.com/paydirect/pay";

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->parameters);

        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(!curl_errno($ch)) {

           curl_close($ch);
           $result = str_replace('/paydirect','https://webpay.interswitchng.com/paydirect',$return);
           echo $result;

        }else {
            echo curl_errno($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
       }
```

Please point me in the right direcction

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" means what exactly, what is the result you're getting and how is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try adding this option

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The replacement looks correct to me. How does the page's source-code look? You can also try setting a [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp).